# R: box plot ggplot for n index categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have this data.frame `A`

```
  row  index   x          y 
    1   1    0.00129    810.77086
    2   1    0.00129     NA
    3   1    0.00129     NA
    4   1    0.00129    1091.93103
    5   1    0.00129    1110.63727
    6   1    0.00129    1111.14589
    7   1    0.00129    855.20836
    8   1    0.00129    705.51621
    9   1    0.00129    593.82147
    10  1    0.00129    637.42397
    11  1    0.00129    596.95761
    12  1    0.00129    584.06459
    13  2    0.00133    640.16478
    14  2    0.00133      NA
    15  2    0.00133      NA
    16  2    0.00133    677.74627
    17  2    0.00133    749.62762
    18  2    0.00133    801.45532
    19  2    0.00133    695.72810
    20  2    0.00133    684.00883
    21  2    0.00133    561.36774
    22  2    0.00133    550.28801
    23  2    0.00133    590.38698
    24  2    0.00133    602.19270
```

I would create boxplot based on index column, i try with ggplot:

```
p <- ggplot(data=A,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=index))
```

R tell me:

```
Warning messages:
1: Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)? 
2: Removed 60750 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot)
```

In the point 2, R tell me 60750 rows, because my true data frame is with 330250 observation, the index change every 1321 row (total i have 250 index). The expected result is a plot where in the axes x there is the column x, in the axes y a boxplot, each one is for 1321 value based on column index, totally are 250 boxplot (330250/1321).
What is wrong? How i can plot this data?

Comment: try adding `grou`p, like so: `ggplot(data=A,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=index, group=index))`

Comment: Yes!!...thank you...simple!!!